# Android screen-size and resolution

Tags: android, xml, drawable, resolution, screen-size

My app works perfectly in resolution 480x800. If I keep the 480x800 resolution but change the screen size to for example 2.7 inches, 3.7 inches or 5.4 inches it still is perfect. But when I change the resolution to for example 640x1066 all the ImageButtons is too small and in the wrong place in all screen sizes... I have created ImageButtons in all four folders(drawable-l, m, h, xh) but still the buttons is not in the correct size..

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ib1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginTop="433dp"
android:background="@drawable/imagebutton1" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ib2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
android:layout_marginTop="436dp"
android:background="@drawable/imagebutton2" />
```

NOTE: My problem is not when I change screen size, but when I change screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 9 patch images?

They work a lot nicer when it comes to things like image buttons, check them out in the Android docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse it will change. You are giving margins(left, top) in `dp` which varies based on the resolutions. To avoid this issue you should do dynamic calculations like dynamically getting screen height and width and setting margins accordingly.